# Getting path from plugin in jQuery.get

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have following code in a plugin of Wp.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function(){
            showUserName(this.value);
        });
        function showUserName(str){
            if(str==''){
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val('');
            }
        jQuery.get("' . plugins_url('FixFormData/getuser.php') . '", { q: str }, function(response){
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                    var arr = [];
                    for(var x in parsed){
                      arr.push(parsed[x]);
                    }
                    jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                    jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need to get the path to getuser.php (which is in my plugin folder) in jQuery.get. I tried many things and none of them are working.

Also in the getuser.php I am using

```
include "../../../wp-config.php";
```

Is it possible that this is/will be causing problems?

Thanks in advance.

Stijn Aerts

Comment: are you just needing to get the URL of the page you are on dynamically?

Comment: I made the OP more clear. I need to get the path to a file in my plugin folder. /my_plugin/getuser.php

Comment: OK, so if you know the page you are on then you are able to know where to find the plugin folder in relationship to the page being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to find the URL information of the displayed page then you can use the   window.location to get the details of the url the page is displayed on.

Some of the different parts below are .

```
    var urlHref = window.location.href;
    var urlHostName = window.location.hostname;
    var urlPathName = window.location.pathname;
```

Once you have this then you can use the parts you need to find the other path/files on your server.

Comment: This is not the solution I want, in wordpress there are things like plugins_url() but I can't get this to work. Your solution would work on my website, but not on someone else's with a different structure.

Comment: This may seem over simplistic but have you tried this ...   var pluginDir = plugins_url();